# Android: Pass rating bar value to dialog

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, ratingbar

My goal is after a rating bar is clicked, the value of this rating bar is passed to a DialogFragment that shows a new ratingbar.

This is my activity code (onCreate)

```
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser){
            RateItemDialogFragment newFragment = new RateItemDialogFragment();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putFloat("ratingValue", rating);
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "rate menu item");

            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my DialogFragment

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();


    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_rate_item, null))

            .setMessage(R.string.title_rating_dialog)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.send, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Send the positive button event back to the host activity
                    mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(RateItemDialogFragment.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Send the negative button event back to the host activity
                    mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(RateItemDialogFragment.this);
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                    RateItemDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            })
    ;

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();

    // set the ratingBar to the right value
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    ((RatingBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar_dialog)).setRating(bundle.getFloat("ratingValue"));

    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return dialog;
}
```

This gives me a JavaNullPointerException on

```
        ((RatingBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar_dialog)).setRating(bundle.getFloat("ratingValue"));
```

I must be doing something wrong in the Fragment lifecycle but I can't figure out where... Thanks!

Comment: I think, you have to retrieve arguments as following
`Bundle args = getArguments();`
And then you can do
`args.getFloat("ratingValue");`

Comment: He already is doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is may not be a child of the dialog.

Try this, look for your view in the inflated dialog view.
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_rate_item, null);
    builder.setView(root)

```
            .setMessage(R.string.title_rating_dialog)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.send, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Send the positive button event back to the host activity
                    mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(RateItemDialogFragment.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Send the negative button event back to the host activity
                    mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(RateItemDialogFragment.this);
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                    RateItemDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
```

And then

```
    ((RatingBar) root.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar_dialog)).setRating(bundle.getFloat("ratingValue"));
```